# What is wrong with this C++ code?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int  n;
    do {
        cout << "Enter a number:";
        cin >> n;
        if (n % 2 == 0)
            cout << "The number is even.\n";
        else
            cout << "The number is odd.\n";
        bool prime;
        for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
            if (n % i == 0)
                prime = true;
        }

        if (prime) {
            cout << "The number is not prime.";
        }
        else
            cout << "The number is prime.";

        cout << "Do you want to continue?[y/n]";
        cin >> ch;
    } while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y');
}
```

If the loop enters once into if(prime) then it never goes in the else.
On first run of loop if 3 is entered, it outputs prime. Then in next if 4 if entered it show not prime but after that whenever any prime number is entered it shows not prime.

Comment: You're breaking out of the loop in the if-clause.

Comment: And `if prime: print("Your number is not prime)` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: _@NafN_ Regarding your title, more important in 1st place: [What is wrong with your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @NafN As the other commenters have said, you need to learn to use a debugger to solve problems like this. And do you know what `break` does? Tutorials exist everywhere for it. I'd look that up if I were you. Be careful using constructs you don't understand, as they lead to issues like this.

Comment: `prime` is not initialized, so it has no predictable value. Initializing it to `false` will make things work much better. Changing its name to `not_prime`, or something else that more clearly describes what it means, will make the code much easier to read.

Comment: @PeteBecker initializing prime to false isn't working

Comment: @NafN That's because it's `break` that's your issue. The not initializing `prime` is just something that would have bitten you later.

Comment: Unless my eyes aren't working, I don't see `break` anywhere. Have you edited your code?

Comment: @ABusyProgrammer Ya, he got rid of the the break. It was in the `if (prime) {` block.

Comment: break is not the problem! still its not working

Comment: Why is `i` declared at the top of the function and not just in the `for` loop (`for (int i = ...)`)? This is not C - keep variables in as narrow a scope as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all your

```
bool prime;
```

is not initialized. Second it should be initialized inside `do while()` loop and it is better to move that variable declaration there:

```
    bool prime = false; // move it here and initialize
    for (i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
        if (n % i == 0)
            prime = true;
    }
```

and you use boolean flag in reverse, which makes your program unreadable, you better fix that:

```
    bool prime = true; // move it here and initialize
    for (i = 2; i < n and prime; ++i) {
        if (n % i == 0) 
            prime = false;
    }
    if (prime) 
        cout << "The number is prime.";
    else
        cout << "The number is not prime.";
```